# Can we use validator class in method parameter with validation application block?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, enterprise-library

I am using validation application block and new in this. My question is that can we give the validator class to method parameter? like used it with WCF

```
public void getTaskList([some validator class] String number) { ....}
```

Regards,
Girish

Comment: You can read the 'Validation instructions CS.pdf' that comes with the Enterprise Library Hands on Labs download: http://bit.ly/e8efoo. It show you all you need about VAB and integrating with ASP.NET and WCF.

Answer (score 0):

imho you should not use a validation framework on simple parameters since they are the contract for the method.

It's just as throwing an `ArgumentNullException` if parameter `User owner` is null and then to validation on the actual `User` object.

If you need validation, put all method arguments in a class and validate that class.